# Angular Material autocomplete shared module

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I use an angular material autocomplete input in multiple components and it always looks the same:

form.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
    <input matInput aria-label="Name" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="nameCtrl" type="text">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let name of filteredNames | async" [value]="name.adlogin">
            <span>{{ name.displayname }}</span>
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

form.component.ts

```
export class FormComponent {

    nameCtrl: new FormControl();
    filteredNames: Observable<any[]>;
    nameList: any = [];

    constructor() {
        this.filteredNames = this.nameCtrl.valueChanges
        .pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(name => name ? this.filterStates(name) : this.nameList.slice())
        );
    }

    filterStates(name: string) {
        return this.nameList.filter(name => {
            const searchStr = name.displayname.toLowerCase();
            return searchStr.indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        });
    }

}
```

What should I do to create a shared module I am able to import if it is needed in a component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a component out of this named "Autocomplete.component.html" and also the ts. You should have the metadata with selector as well.

Then create a SharedModule and import the component inside the declarations also under exports.

now you should be able to use the component anywhere within other modules by importing SharedModule under imports.